# send image file to client using java without sockets

Tags: java, cordova

I am using file download phonegap in my client side (ipad) to download an image file from the internet. Now I need to send the image through my java server. I am sending the image  as `stream`, but the client side needs a file. If I send the image file as stream it means it's not downloading the image file. How do I send the image file as a file without using `sockets`?

My server side code is:

```
String file_location=request.getQueryString();
String[] splitable=file_location.split("&");
String[] document_name=splitable[0].split("=");
String[] document_page=splitable[1].split("=");

PDFDocumentManag er documentManager;
try
{
    ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    //String location=loadClass.fileLocation(document_name[1]);
    String location="D:/Processing/893210.pdf";
    documentManager = new PDFDocumentManager(new File(location));
    documentManager.setPageNum(Integer.parseInt(document_page[1]));
    response.setContentType("image/gif"); 
    ImageIO.write(documentManager.getImage(), "gif", new File("D:/testing/out.gif"));
}
```

Comment: If you're using the Internet, you're using sockets. Your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understand your Question correctly, but you MIGHT need "Content Disposition"
try

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
```